# Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409) Tensorflow error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm doing a simple CNN algorithm for a MNIST dataset and ran into such a problem. I know that there could million reasons for this to happen in tensorflow but if anyone has an idea what to actually do I'd really happy.

So this is the output:

```
2021-06-06 00:48:30.854140: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:34.334009: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-06-06 00:48:34.335490: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.401858: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.56GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 119.24GiB/s
2021-06-06 00:48:35.402113: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.409854: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.410015: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.414546: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.416442: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.423427: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.427473: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.428431: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.428643: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-06-06 00:48:35.429282: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-06-06 00:48:35.430229: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.56GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 119.24GiB/s
2021-06-06 00:48:35.430583: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.430727: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.430854: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.430981: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.431101: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.431228: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.431346: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.431522: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:35.432695: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-06-06 00:48:36.075767: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-06-06 00:48:36.075939: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-06-06 00:48:36.076035: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2021-06-06 00:48:36.076312: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2903 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1650, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2021-06-06 00:48:36.077384: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv_1 (Conv2D)              (None, 28, 28, 32)        832       
_________________________________________________________________
pool_1 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 14, 14, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv_2 (Conv2D)              (None, 14, 14, 64)        51264     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 12544)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc_1 (Dense)                 (None, 1024)              12846080  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc_2 (Dense)                 (None, 10)                10250     
=================================================================
Total params: 12,908,426
Trainable params: 12,908,426
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/80
2021-06-06 00:48:36.946333: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-06-06 00:48:37.020602: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:37.638591: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-06-06 00:48:38.228603: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

As you can see, the first epoch of my algorithm starts and suddenly the program breaks, giving this output. Version of tf: 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Update tf to 2.5.0 was the solution...